# How do I query individual thumbnail-namespace attributes with the gio command?

Tags: gnome3, gvfs, thumbnails

The `gio` shell command replaces the `gvfs-` suite for working with local and remote files on Gnome systems, using Gio over the Gvfs backend. For the most part it's quite effective, but I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding its tools for examining the boolean attributes in the `thumbnail` namespace.

`gio info $URI` will display all of the attributes for a supported file URI or local file path. `gio info -a $selection $URI` allows attribute namespaces or individual attributes to be queried. Mostly that works fine:

```
% gio info -a access test.png
uri: file:///var/tmp/test.png
attributes:
  access::can-read: TRUE
  access::can-write: TRUE
  access::can-execute: FALSE
  access::can-delete: TRUE
  access::can-trash: FALSE
  access::can-rename: TRUE

% gio info -a thumbnail test.png
uri: file:///var/tmp/test.png
attributes:
  thumbnail::path: /home/ferd/.cache/thumbnails/large/0953b0d1f71f9066deee9ac3fb72243b.png
  thumbnail::is-valid: TRUE
```

But if I try to query individual attributes, things get wonky once I'm in the thumbnail space:

```
% gio info -a access::can-read test.png
uri: file:///var/tmp/test.png
attributes:
  access::can-read: TRUE

% gio info -a thumbnail::path test.png
uri: file:///var/tmp/test.png
attributes:
  thumbnail::path: /home/ferd/.cache/thumbnails/large/0953b0d1f71f9066deee9ac3fb72243b.png

% gio info -a thumbnail::is-valid test.png
uri: file:///var/tmp/test.png
attributes:

% gio info -a thumbnail::failed test.png
uri: file:///var/tmp/test.png
attributes:
```

What's going on here? Why can't I query attributes like `thumbnail::is-valid` or `thumbnail::failed` individually? No matter what I do, `gio info` always produces no attribute output, whether the value is `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or if the attribute is absent entirely, which makes it awfully hard to determine which of those it is.

(Obviously I could query `-a thumbnail` and parse the output, this question is more about the confusing behavior of `gio` than about how to extract the values in question.)

I'm on a Fedora 26 machine, currently, with Gnome 3.24.3 and `/usr/bin/gio` from `glib2-2.52.3-2.fc26.x86_64`. The filesystem is `ext4`, and behavior is exactly the same for files in `/home/ferd/Pictures` as in these `/var/tmp/` examples.

### Update

At Sebastian's suggestion, filed as [gnome bug #791325](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=791325).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really an issue with the `gio` command, but rather how this attribute is generated. The code where the attribute is generated is found in `glib/gio/glocalfileinfo.c`. [This line](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/glocalfileinfo.c?h=2.54.2#n1977) is responsible for behavior you are seeing. It causes the `is-valid` attribute to only be generated if the query includes the path as well. I don't know if this is done intentionally, because the validity of the thumbnail is connected to its path or if this is just bug. You can [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib) and bring this to the attention of the developers.

Comment: That is truly fascinating, _and_ truly weird. You're quite correct: I can query the `thumbnail::` booleans using `gio info` as long as I _also_ query the `thumbnail::path` — even if it's not present! `gio info -a thumbnail::path,thumbnail::failed $file` for a file with a failed thumbnail will output the `thumbnail::failed: TRUE` result, whereas querying it without the path will not. ...That seems **way** too wonky to be working as intended, I'm definitely going to file a bug. Thanks.